# Question on Status of Islamic and Islam-related Sects

Tags: shiism, kufr, sects

What status is agreed the following minor Islamic sects and partly Islam-related religions according to the four Sunni fiqh and the Shia School of Qom:

- Muslim (with respect to marriage, heritage, etc.)
- Dhimmi
- Other protected status has been agreed to
- unprotected Kafir (agreement refused)
  (there will be no possible answer in case an agreement has never been seached for)

Among old religions

- Alawite (Syria)
- Alevite (Turkey)
- Druse (Lebanon)

Among new movements, religions and sects

- Quranists
- Ahmaddiyya
- Inayati
- Baha'i

I know that many users on this platform (or majority muslims in general) will disagree with most or all aforementioned groups. I would like to discourage any discussion theron and ask to restrain answers to official fatwa or statements according to a school.

Comment: This looks like a question which will end up too broad.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes, it is indeed a broad question, and it would be a huge work to give the ultimate answer. But if several users contribute as to their knowledge, this may lead to a good overview.

Comment: That is not how this site works an answer should fully, address the question else it is not an acceptable answer. What you are asking for is in conflict to the stackexchange policy.

Comment: Dhimmi and Kafir are not mutually exclusive categories. A Kafir is any non-muslim, and a Dhimmi is a kafir who has agreed to pay Jizya and been granted protection.  Protected status (dhimmi, musta’min or mu‘aahid) is granted to groups and individuals when the make an agreement with the Islamic state, it is not implied just by their following a religion.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Do you have an idea how to solve the problem that the question is too broad? I would be happy if only some answers could be given. I am always writing difficult questions because for the easy ones I can find out myself...

Comment: A first step would be a restriction on shi'a/sunni perspective... Or a seperate question for each "movement"

Comment: So I am going to put some more particular questions; maybe I manage to write a summary as a community answer here...